# Yii Framework + Infinite Scroll + Masonry Callback not working

Tags: yii, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I know that InfiniteScroll and Masonry work well together. But I am using the Infinite Scroll Extension of Yii (called yiinfinite-scroll) and tried to apply Masonry on it. Infinite Scroll for itself works perfectly, Masonry for itself too. But after InfiniteScroll tries to load a new set of images (I've got an image page), the callback part of InfiniteScroll doesn't seem to fire, because the newly appended elements don't have any masonry code in it and appear behind the first visible items. (I know that this bug is reported often, but the solutions I found so far didn't work for me).

My structure for showing the picture looks like this:

```
<div class="items">
 <div class="pic">...</pic>
 <div class="pic">...</pic>
...
</div>
```

The first page load looks like this

```
<div class="items masonry" style="...">
   <div class="pic masonry-brick" ...></div>
   <div class="pic masonry-brick" ...></div>
   ...
</div> // everything's fine, masonry is injected into the code
```

After infinite scroll dynamically loads new images these look like this:

```
<div class="items masonry" ...></div>
   <div class="pic masonry-brick" ...></div>
   ...
   // appended pics:
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <div class="pic"></div>
</div> // so no masonry functionality was applied
```

My Masonry Code:

```
    $(function (){  
        var $container = $('.items');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.pic',
            columnWidth: 405
        });
      });
   });

   $container.infinitescroll({
        // normally, the options are found here. but as I use infinitescroll as a Yii extension, the plugin is already initiated with options
        }
    },
    // trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
      // hide new items while they are loading
      var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
      // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
      $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        // show elems now they're ready
        $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
      });
  });  
  });
```

I also tried to copy and replace the current InfiniteScroll-min.js file in the extension folder by the newest one. Same effect...

Best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 5):

Okay I found a solution. I post it here if somebody else has the same issue:

I just modified the YiinfiniteScroller Class from the Yiinfinite Scroll Yii Extension and added the callback part for Infinite Scroll which was missing:

```
 private function createInfiniteScrollScript() {
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
            uniqid(),
            "$('{$this->contentSelector}').infinitescroll(".$this->buildInifiniteScrollOptions().", ".$this->callback.");"
    );
}
```

At the beginning of the class I added the line
    public $callback;
to use it later in the method.

Then you can call the Widget with an additional option callback, for example like this:

```
'callback' => 'function( newElements ) {
                    // hide new items while they are loading
                    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
                    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
                    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                      // show elems now theyre ready
                      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                      $(".items").masonry( "appended", $newElems, true ); 
                    });
                }',
```

Works like charm.